# Unit Test NUnit Api using middleware exeption .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nunit, asp.net-core-webapi

I recently added some middleware for exception handling, which caused some unit tests to fail for me.

Before controller:

```
[HttpPost("Create")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([FromBody] ModelDTO model)
{
    try
    {
        if (model == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        //...
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex);
    }
}
```

Before test returns BadRequest and InternalServerError

```
[Test]
public async Task When_Add_Return_BadRequest()
{
    // Arrange
    var nameDB = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    var serviceProvider = CreateContext(nameDB);

    var db = serviceProvider.GetService<ClassContext>();
    db.Add(model);

    // Act
    mapper.Map<Model>(request).ReturnsForAnyArgs(model);

    var controller = new ProductController(db, shared, mapper);

    var result = await controller.Create(null) as ObjectResult;

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(400, result.StatusCode);
        Assert.That(result, Is.TypeOf<BadRequestObjectResult>());
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task When_Add_Return_InternalServerError()
    {
        //Arrange
        var nameDB = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var serviceProvider = CreateContext(nameDB);

        var db = serviceProvider.GetService<NAFContext>();
        db.Add(model);

        //Act
        mapper.Map<ARCIGASTOS>(request).ThrowsForAnyArgs(x => { throw new Exception(); });

        var controller = new ProductController(db, shared, mapper);

        var result = await controller.Create(purchaseRequest) as ObjectResult;

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(500, result.StatusCode);
    }
}
```

This worked fine for me. But when incorporating the middleware remove the blocks try/catch.

Because they are handled in the middleware.

```
    [HttpPost("Create")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create([FromBody] ModelDTO model)
    {
        if (model == null)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("RequiredField");
        }

        ///...
        return Ok();
    }
```

This is the middleware:

```
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(httpContext);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await HandleExceptionAsync(httpContext, ex);
        }
    }

    private async Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        var response = context.Response;

        string errorResponse;

        switch (exception)
        {
            case ApplicationException ex:
                if (ex.Message.Contains("Invalid token"))
                {
                    response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                    errorResponse = exception.Message;
                    break;
                }
                response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                errorResponse = exception.Message;
                break;

            case KeyNotFoundException ex:
                response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
                errorResponse = exception.Message;
                break;

            default:
                response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                errorResponse = null != exception.InnerException ? exception.InnerException.Message : exception.Message;
                break;
        }
  
        var result = JsonSerializer.Serialize(errorResponse);
        await context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
    }
```

How should I handle this type of test?

Comment: You should explain how you hooked into the middleware. It needs to be below the tests and it may need to be injected into the tests independently from how you inject it into your actual app.

Comment: I don't inject it, I just initialize it at startup and it catches all exceptions automatically. app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware>();

Comment: Yes,  that's what I meant. Depending how and where you do that initialization, you may be catching the exceptions, which NUnit uses to communicate test results.

Comment: Does this help you? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: It will be that I should treat the tests in another way, no longer go by request testing when it fails, but to do a unit or integration test for only the middleware?